# How do I add multiple recipients to an email in Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I've been trying to add multiple recipients to a Mailer class by using the following code in Rails 4:

```
#/app/mailers/newsletter.rb
class Newsletter < ApplicationMailer

  default to: Proc.new { Admin.pluck(:email) },
          from: 'notification@example.com'

  def sample_email
    mail(subject: "Newsletter")
  end

end

#/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    ...
    if @message.save
      Newsletter.sample_email.deliver_now
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

end
```

The problem is that when I create a new message from the messages controller, I only recieve an email on one of the admin accounts (The first one) - My goal is to have the same email be sent to all the admins in my database.

I've obviously missed something, but I don't  know what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the Array is sufficient!

```
default to: Admin.pluck(:email)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply - I still only receive an email on my first admin account though. Where else could I have messed up?

Comment: If you have nil values then I recommend `default to: Admin.pluck(:email) - [nil]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. I'll try to add some more info - maybe the error is somewhere else. I'm using Heroku for hosting and Sendgrid to send the emails. I've got my Sendgrid credentials set by using environment variables and I've got my smtp settings configured in my production.rb file

Comment: `Admin.all.collect(&:email)`

Comment: The email is still only being sent to the first account - I checked the logs and the first email is the only one getting passed as well. I tried manually creating the array earlier ["example1@mail.com", "example2@mail.com"] and that seemed to work, but it defeats the whole purpose of doing it this way since you have to manually update the array. Any suggestions as to why that's happening?

Comment: Then the only conclusion is that there must be something wrong with the array or emails that you pluck. Run `Admin.pluck(:email)` in your console and check the data and see if all are correct? CauseI think after the first email then next one is in wrong format thats why the sending of emails fails.

Comment: Also turn your `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in config/environments/development.rb to debug this.

Comment: Ok, something interesting happened. I just copied the smtp configuration settings from production.rb to development.rb and tried to do it in development mode. This time both email addresses were passed, but I got an "execution expired" error. Any idea why it's passing both email addresses in development but not in production?

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30124ms (ActiveRecord: 27.9ms)

Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:24:in `create'

Comment: Before the error it says that the mail was sent to the email addresses I've specified followed by the email's markup

Comment: Btw, this is line 24 in messages_controller: Newsletter.sample_email.deliver_now

Comment: you could try using 'pry-rails' to debug this situation, To know more about pry check this => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfFf2-KJNTU

Comment: here's a reference to debug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144150/cant-figure-out-what-this-error-means-rails-netopentimeout-execution-expire

Comment: Oops - I just realized I only created the second admin account in my development environment and not in my production environment. It's kinda hard to send an email to multiple users when you only have one haha. Anyway, your solution worked flawlessly - thanks for your help and I hope I didn't waste too much of your time

Comment: No worries mate! Always here to help! Could you also upvote it please?

Comment: It doesn't show my upvote before I reach a reputation level of 15, but it has been recorded. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The mail recipients must be a string where the mail addresses are separated with a comma.
Exemple: "first@example.com, second@example.com"

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I just solved the problem with a great amount of help from @Aniket - I just wanted to add that it also accepts an array instead of a string. Example: ["first@example.com", "second@example.com"]